# in JTable how to traverse focus of TableCellEditor Focus along with the cell Focus

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using JTextField as a DefaultCellEditor for the all column of the JTable.  When I edit a cell and press Enter then the focus go to the next cell. But when I write in this cell then the values are inserted into the previous cell. But I want that this value should be entered into the focused cell how to do that

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class VoucherDialog extends JDialog {
    JPanel contentPane;
    JLabel jl1,jl2,jl3;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    String[] column_headers= {"SN","REF","DATE","PARTICULARS","AMOUNT",};
    String[][] items= {};
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    TableModel tm;

    ResultSet rs=null;
    String c1,c2;
    int rowz,col;
    JTextField snField,dateField,particularField,refField;
    JFormattedTextField amountField;
    JComboBox<String> ref_Cb;

    JPopupMenu popup;
    NumberFormat amountFormat;
    private double amount = 100000;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            VoucherDialog dialog = new VoucherDialog();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     * @throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException 
     * @throws IllegalAccessException 
     * @throws InstantiationException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws ParseException 
     */
    public VoucherDialog() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException,NumberFormatException, ParseException
    {
        contentPane=new JPanel();
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //setBounds(100, 100, 571, 322);
        setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            ActionListener a=new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
                    dispose(); 
                }   
            };
            this.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(a,KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE,0),JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1, 0, 0));

        jl1=new JLabel();
        jl1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jl1.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.BOLD, 16));
        jl1.setText(c1);
        panel.add(jl1);

        jl2=new JLabel();
        jl2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jl2.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        jl2.setText(c2);
        panel.add(jl2);

        jl3=new JLabel();
        jl3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jl3.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        jl3.setText("**Product Master** ");
        panel.add(jl3);


        model=new DefaultTableModel(items,column_headers)
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
            {
                if(column == 0 )
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        };

        table = new JTable(model){
            //      private boolean inLayout;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) 
            {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                if (isRowSelected(row)) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    c.setBackground(Color.white);
                    c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                return c;
            }

        };

        table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    // Select the current cell
                    rowz = table.getSelectedRow();
                    col = table.getSelectedColumn();
                    int totalrows=table.getRowCount();
                    if((rowz+1)==totalrows)
                    {
                        model.addRow(new Object[] {"","","","",""});
                    }
                    //table.repaint(); 
                } 


                if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_INSERT)
                {
                    int row=table.getSelectedRow();
                    model.insertRow(row,new Object[] {"1","","","",""} );

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    // Select the current cell
                    rowz = table.getSelectedRow();
                    col = table.getSelectedColumn();

                    int totalrows=table.getRowCount();

                    if((rowz+1)==totalrows)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<table.getColumnCount();i++)
                        { 
                            int x=0;
                            if(table.getSelectedRow()>0)
                            {
                                x=Integer.valueOf(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow()-1,0).toString());
                                x=x+1;
                            }
                            else
                                x=0;
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }



        });


        //to make the Border at selected cell
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
        {
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus,int row,int column)
            {
                super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 
                //setBorder(noFocusBorder);
                if (hasFocus)
                {
                    setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
                    // to scrolling JTable automatically to the Bottom
                    scrollToVisible(table,table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn());

                }
                return this;

            }
        });


        table.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
        table.setShowHorizontalLines(false);



        // to work the enter key like the tab
        InputMap im = table.getInputMap();
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Action.NextCell");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0), "Action.NextCell");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "Action.NextCell");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "Action.PreviousCell");

        ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();
        am.put("Action.NextCell", new NextCellActioin(table));
        am.put("Action.PreviousCell", new PreviousCellAction(table));

        //to remove the vertical lines of the Table Header
        for(int i = 0; i <column_headers.length; i++)
        {
            TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setHeaderRenderer(new HeaderRenderer());
        }  

        table.setRowHeight(25);
        //table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
        table.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.BOLD, 16));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(130);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(130);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMinWidth(250);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(250);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(250);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(250);


        TableColumn snColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        snField=new JTextField();
        snField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        snField.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        snColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(snField));


        TableColumn refColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        refField=new JFormattedTextField();
        refField.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        refField.setEditable(true);
        refField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        refColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(refField)); 

        TableColumn dateColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        JFormattedTextField dateTextField = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("##/##/####"));
        dateTextField.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        dateTextField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        dateColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(dateTextField));

        TableColumn particularColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
        particularField=new JTextField();
        particularField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        particularField.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        particularColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(particularField));

        TableColumn amountColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
        //amountField=new JFormattedTextField(createAmountFormatter());
        amountField=new JFormattedTextField(amountFormat);
        amountField.setValue(amount);

        //amountField.addFocusListener(l);
        amountField.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        amountField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        //amountField.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 14));
        amountColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(amountField));

        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(); 
        scrollPane.setViewportBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants. HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants. VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        scrollPane.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );


        for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
        {

            model.addRow(new Object[] {"1","","","",""});
            table.setValueAt(i+1, i,0);
        }

        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }




    // to scrolling JTable automatically to the Bottom
    public static  void scrollToVisible(final JTable table, final int rowIndex, final int vColIndex) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(rowIndex, vColIndex, false));
            }
        });
    }




    class NextCellActioin extends AbstractAction {

        private JTable table;

        public NextCellActioin(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();

            int colCount = table.getColumnCount();
            int rowCount = table.getRowCount();

            int x;
            System.out.println("NExt");
            do
            {
                col++;
                if (col >= colCount) {
                    col = 0;
                    row++;
                }

                if (row >= rowCount) {
                    row = 0;
                }
                TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col);
                x=column.getWidth();
                if(x!=0)
                    col--;
                //else if(x==0)
                //setDefaultValue(col);
            }while(x==0); 
            col++;
            if (col >= colCount) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }

            if (row >= rowCount) {
                row = 0;
            }

            table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
            table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(col, col);
        }

    }

    class PreviousCellAction extends AbstractAction {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JTable table;

        public PreviousCellAction(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();

            int colCount = table.getColumnCount();
            int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
            System.out.println("Previous");

            int x;
            do
            {
                col--;
                System.out.println("3"+col);
                if (col<0)
                {
                    col =colCount-1;
                    row--;

                    System.out.println("1"+col);
                }
                if (row<0) 
                {
                    row =rowCount-1;

                }
                x = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).getWidth();
                //x=column.getWidth();
                if(x!=0)
                    col++;
                //else if(x==0)
                System.out.println("2"+x);
                //setDefaultValue(col);
            }while(x==0); 
            col--;

            if (col<0)
            {
                /*if (row==0) 
                {
                  row =rowCount;  
                }
                else*/
                System.out.println("2"+col);
                col =colCount-1;
                row--;
                System.out.println("3"+col);

            }

            if (row<0) 
            {
                row =rowCount-1;

            }

            table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
            table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(col, col);
        }

    }
}

//this class used to hide the tableHeader
class HeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean hasFocus,
            boolean isSelected,
            int row,
            int col)
    {

        setText(value.toString());
        setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: `But I want that this value should be entered into the focused cell how to do that` - this is the default behaviour of an editor. If it doesn't work, then the problem is with your custom code. There is too much code for us to look at. So start from the beginning. Just use the default editor to verify it works. Then use the custom editor and verify it works, Then customize the next/previous actions of the table and verify it works. When it stops working then you know what you changed and you know where to concentrate you time to fix the problem.

Comment: You may want to check out [Table Tabbing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/table-tabbing/) for a helper class that allows you to easily customize the default behaviour of a table action.